# Search elements in two arrays in the given range using numpy.where()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bigdata

I'm working with big arrays of geophysical data. I have two numpy arrays that have sizes 320x340: first `XLAT` contains the latitude of every point in the grid, the second `XLON` contains the longitude of every point in the grid. So every `i, j` describes the point on the ground with latitude `XLAT[i][j]` and longitude `XLON[i][j]`.

I have point with coordinates `P_LAT` and `P_LON` and I have to find the closest 4 point to given point.

First of all I wrote simple function that run through all the point on x-axis and y-axis, but it makes 320*340 = 108 800 iterations and works very very slow (~0.5 seconds for every point):

```
    for i in range(0, lat-1):
            for j in range(0, lon-1):

                    if ST_LON >= XLON[i][j] and \
                            ST_LON < XLON[i][j + 1] and \
                            ST_LAT >= XLAT[i][j] and \
                            ST_LAT < XLAT[i + 1][j]:
                            return (True, i, i + 1, j, j + 1)
```

Then I found some info about `numpy.where()` and wrote this code:

```
    for i in range(0, lat):
            rows = numpy.where((XLON[i] >= ST_LON - 0.5) & (XLON[i] <= ST_LON + 0.5))

        for j in rows[0]:
            if ST_LON >= XLON[i][j] and \
                            ST_LON < XLON[i][j + 1] and \
                            ST_LAT >= XLAT[i][j] and \
                            ST_LAT < XLAT[i + 1][j]:
                return (True, i, i + 1, j, j + 1)
```

This function works much faster (~0.015 sec for every point), but I don't think it is the right and beautiful solution.

So my final question is how can I find the items in both arrays, that satisfy the conditions:

`XLON[i] <= ST_LON <= XLON[i][j+1]` and `XLAT[i][j] <= ST_LAT <= XLAT[i+1][j]`

and this should work quickly?

Comment: Do you mean XLON[i][j] instead of XLON[i] in your line with the conditions?

Comment: You have set two goals. 1: find the closest 4 points. 2: find the items, that satisfy the conditions. Which is what you want?

Comment: XLON and XLAT are both have size 320x340. The condition is to find the 4 closest points and I tried to it with the given condition.

Comment: You have not answered the first question. What do we know about the XLON and XLAT data? Eg. XLON[i][j] < XLON[i][j+1] ? What about XLON[i][j] and XLON[i+1][j] ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the programming task, so let me repeat in my own words:

You have two 2dim arrays XLAT and XLON. They are some kind of translating arrays to get the latitude / longitude from some grid.

From your code examples I conclude: 
**XLON[i][j]==XLON[h][j] is valid for all i,h in range(0,lat)** ?!
(Maybe there is a good reason to have that object, but it doesn't look very performant)

So the most simple solution should be to just treat bot dimensions seperately:

```
for i in range(0, lat-1):
    if (XLON[i][0] >= ST_LON - 0.5) & (XLON[i][0] <= ST_LON + 0.5):
        break
for j in range(0, lon-1):
    if (XLAT[0][j] >= ST_LAT - 0.5) & (XLAT[0][j] <= ST_LAT + 0.5)):
        break   
return (True, i, i + 1, j, j + 1)
```

You can also replace the if-break statement with np.where.

I am not sure if I got you right. If my answer does not help, it would be very usefull to supply us with a small working example python code with XLON, XLAT reduced to, say, 5x4 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all replies, I found a fast solution using `numpy.where()` with big condition, but it is a bit not beautiful and not aesthetic :)

```
    #Calculate the step
    dLAT = numpy.abs(self.XLON[0][1] - self.XLON[0][0]) * 3
    dLON = numpy.abs(self.XLAT[1][0] - self.XLAT[0][0]) * 3

    #Get the rows and cells satisfying the condition
    rows, cells = numpy.where(((self.XLON >= ST_LON - dLON) & (self.XLON <= ST_LON + dLON)) & ((self.XLAT >= ST_LAT - dLAT) & (self.XLAT <= ST_LAT + dLAT)))

    #Loop through all the values
    for i in range(0, len(rows)):

        #Get the indexes
        current_lat = rows[i]
        next_lat = rows[i] + 1
        current_lon = cells[i]
        next_lon = cells[i] + 1

        #Check the point
        if ST_LON >= self.XLON[current_lat][current_lon] and ST_LON < self.XLON[current_lat][next_lon] and \
            ST_LAT >= self.XLAT[current_lat][current_lon] and ST_LAT < self.XLAT[next_lat][current_lon]:

            return(True, current_lat, next_lat, current_lon, next_lon)

    return (False, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```